# Date Changes when retrieved from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query that retrieves a date from my database. My problem is the date changes from what is stored in the database.

In the database the date is `2017-01-31 23:01:00`. When I retrieve it from the database and `echo` the date it is now `2017-02-01 01:01:00`.

What is causing this change and how can I fix it?

My code is below. The code is in a Laravel controller class:

```
$test_data = UserTest::where('test_id', '=', $id)
    ->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
    ->select('date')
    ->get();

echo $test_data[0]->date; // outputs: 2017-02-01 01:01:00
```

**Edit:** In Laravel `config/app.php` my timezone setting is: `'timezone' => 'Australia/Melbourne',`. My PHP.ini has `date.timezone = UTC`.

Comment: Almost certainly a timezone difference. What timezone are you using for the dates in your database? And what is your default timezone setting for PHP?

Comment: @MarkBaker how can I make PHP not alter the timezone? All dates stored in the database are local to a user. Ie, these are medical tests and the date represents when this test was done in that patients local time. PHP should not alter the date at all and just pull it straight out of the database.

Comment: It would be better to store the dates in the db as UTC and only display for the appropriate timezone, or you also need to ensure that you store the timezone in the database as well, and use that to ensure that the date is correctly displayed

Comment: Or, try to use datetime instead of timestamp

Answer (score 0):

In config/app.php you can set your default timezone

```
'timezone' => 'Australia/Sydney', // or simply 'UTC'
```

The records you saved previously would still be offset. But those you save from now on will be correct.